How do I migrate scriptable render passes to RenderGraph Api?
I updated my unity project to Unity 6. Everything worked perfectly but every time I opened the editor to work on my project, a warning shows:warning
How do I resolve it?
Thanks in Advance.
PS I am using URP.
I browsed the web trying to find anything, but Unity 6 is new and most of the people don't use it yet so I found nothing.

The RenderGraph API was already introduced in earlier versions - see https://discussions.unity.com/t/introduction-of-render-graph-in-the-universal-render-pipeline-urp/930355 - it is only until now in Unity 6 (the LTS of 2023) that you get this deprecation warning and for now (luckily) can still use the compatibility mode in the meantime

Yeah, But How do I fix it?

you read the API and replicate whatever you do in your ScriptableRenderPass using the new API ... in particular https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@17.0/manual/render-graph-writing-a-render-pipeline.html
